# Markdown for NVDA or similar screen readers

Tags: screen-readers, nvda

I'm working on web application and our team wants to make it more accessible. In particular, we want to do a better support for people who can't see (using screen readers).

One of the popular solutions is NVDA. After reading their doc [here](https://www.nvaccess.org/files/nvda/documentation/userGuide.html), it's not clear - do they support a custom markdown?

Can I use some attributes/tags/metadata so that NVDA read stuff differently? For example:
[Google](https://google.com) will be read as 'Google'. Can I decorate it in some way, so that it will be read as 'Link to Google'?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as a custom mark-up for screen readers. Well, there is something like that, I'll tell you about it below.
Basically, when you try to make your web site more accessible (a very good thing to do, btw!), you should minimize your impact on screen reader users. By "impact" I mean that your goal should be that your blind user would see just the same thing as a sighted user, but as the web site developer, you give him/her this ability to see, navigate, open, click and so on, and so forth.

There is a way to customize the layout, though. It is called [WAI-ARIA](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/). You can do lots of crazy (and smart) stuff with it, it is great and mighty, but the first rule of the fight club, I mean, WAI-ARIA practices is:

> If you can use a native HTML element or attribute with the semantics and behavior you require already built in, instead of re-purposing an element and adding an ARIA role, state or property
>   to make it accessible, then do so.
>   — [from here](https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/).

I.e.: If you can *not to use* ARIA, don't use it.
Let's take your example with the link to Google: you want your blind user to see the "Google" text and to understand that it is a link, right? Well, I'll tell you what you should do to achieve this. And you need to do... drum roll... nothing! NVDA, or JAWS (which you definitely should test with, it's a major player!), or TalkBack on Android, or VoiceOver on Apple devices, will say: "Link Google", or "Google link" (depends on the screen reader and on particular user's settings). that's all.
Of course you might have done this (but don't do it in any way!):

```
<a href="https://google.com" aria-label="Link to Google"><span aria-hidden="true">Google</span></a>
```

See how crazy (and mighty!) it is? Thus you're telling the screen reader that you need your custom text to be read and hide your main link text (just in case; I've just tested with JAWS, everything works even without the `aria-hidden` attribute, so it's merely for an example).
However, if your link is a `span` with some fancy styling, ARIA is your everything: you just say `<span role="link">`, and your users will get a pleasant experience instead of trying to find which word to click.
And a last example: in Bootstrap there are lots of decorations like

```
<i class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i>
```

If they are on a link (and mostly they are), some screen readers such as JAWS would report two links, one with text, and one empty, just "link". In those cases it is really good to hide this stuff from screen readers:

```
        <i class="fas fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Comment: Thank you Andre, very detailed answer with examples!

Answer (score 0):

[NVDA](https://www.nvaccess.org/), like [JAWS](https://www.freedomscientific.com/Products/Blindness/JAWS), [VoiceOver](https://www.apple.com/accessibility/mac/vision/), [Talkback](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6283677?hl=en), and several others, is a [screen reader](http://www.afb.org/prodBrowseCatResults.aspx?CatID=49).  A screen reader is software that a low-vision or no-vision user will use to access their computer.  If you write semantically correct html, then your app will automatically work with a screen reader.

To create semantically correct html, the W3C has created a set of guidelines, call the [Web Content Accessibility Guidelines](https://www.w3.org/WAI/standards-guidelines/wcag/) (WCAG) that outlines things you can do to improve your web application to make it available for the greatest number of people.

It includes things like having alternate text for images, having labels for form elements, using well-worded text for links, and using the proper html tags for semantic elements, such as `<h1>` for headings, `<ul>` for lists, `<table>` for tables of data, etc.

When [native html](https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#rule1) semantic elements can't be used, for whatever reason, then there are ARIA [attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#x6-6-definitions-of-states-and-properties-all-aria-attributes) and [roles](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#role_definitions) that can be applied to give screen reading software a clue as to what type of object you are trying to convey.

So, there is no markdown for NVDA or any other screen reader.  You just have to be smart in your use of html.